# How to realize parsing of own html tags in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, state-machine

I have task to realize own tags that making text **bold**, underline or strikethrough with any nesting.
Like a

```
*bold text* _underlinetext_ -strikethrough-
```

Also I need to make own hyperlink like a

```
[link | http://stackoverflow.com]
```

The first thought that came - it apply regexp. The code:

```
View.prototype.parseText = function(text) {

text = text.replace(/\*([^\*]+)\*/g, '<b>$1</b>');
text = text.replace(/\_([^\_]+)\_/g, '<u>$1</u>');
text = text.replace(/\-([^\-]+)\-/g, '<s>$1</s>');
text = text.replace(/\[([^\|].+)\|(.+)\]/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');

return text;};
```

It's working but I need extensibility. Regex is not a good idea, since it's hardcoded. How to realize that task with finite state machine (or any jQuery plugin))? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Any kind of parsing is going to involve hardcoding.  Unless you're trying to make a system that is capable of dynamically determining what should be parsed into HTML?  That would get complicated extremely quickly.

Comment: Try looking at an existing parser to see how it works.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using one of the many syntaxes that already exist?  You're not going to be able to write a magical parser that can somehow figure out an infinite amount of possibilities for markup.  (You could of course have multiple syntaxes for the same thing though, like `**text**` and `[b]text[/b]` both boldening `text`.)

Comment: You are rigth. But such a task. Only user tags :) For example, i need to add new tag. With state machine its be easy. Just add new state. Just look implementation of fsm calculator for example. [example](https://github.com/milgoff/Calculator)

Comment: Ah, so it's not dynamic then, but rather extensible.  That's definitely a lot more manageable.  You could just write a parser and you're basically there.  You'd just have to be mindful to keep the parser (and whatever is using it) easily extensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you the following implementation http://jsfiddle.net/NwRCm/5/

It uses the State design pattern (little modified because of JavaScript and the purpose). Under the surface all states are implemented with regular expressions but that's the most efficient way, in my opinion.

```
/* View definition */

function View(container) {
    this.container = container;
    this._parsers = [];
    this._currentState = 0;
};

View.prototype.parse = function(text) {

    var self = this;
    this._parsers.forEach(function (e) {
        self._parse(e);
    });

    return this.container.innerHTML;

};

View.prototype._parse = function (parser) {
    var text = parser.parse(this.container.innerHTML);
    this.container.innerHTML = text;
    return text;
};

View.prototype.nextState = function () {
    if (this._currentState < this._parsers.length) {
        return this._parse(this._parsers[this._currentState++]);
    }
    return null;
};

View.prototype.addParser = function (parser) {
    if (parser instanceof Parser) {
        return this._parsers.push(parser);
    } else {
        throw 'The parser you\'re trying to add is not an instance of Parser';
    }
};
/* end of the View definition */

/* Simulation of interface */
function Parser() {};

Parser.prototype.parse = function () {
    throw 'Not implemented!';
};

/* Implementation of bold parser */
function BoldParser() {};

BoldParser.prototype = new Parser();

BoldParser.prototype.parse = function (text) {
    text = text.replace(/\*([^\*]+)\*/g, '<b>$1</b>');
    return text;
};

/* Implementation of underline parser */
function UnderlineParser() {};

UnderlineParser.prototype = new Parser();

UnderlineParser.prototype.parse = function (text) {
    text = text.replace(/\_([^\_]+)\_/g, '<u>$1</u>');
    return text;
};

/* Link parser */
function LinkParser() {};

LinkParser.prototype = new Parser();

LinkParser.prototype.parse = function (text) {
    text = text.replace(/\[([^\|].+)\|(.+)\]/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
    return text;
};


var v = new View(document.getElementById('container'));
v.addParser(new UnderlineParser());
v.addParser(new BoldParser());
v.addParser(new LinkParser());
v.nextState();
v.nextState();
v.nextState();
```

​Let me look a little deeper in the implementation.
First we have a base "class" (constructor function) View. Each view has it's base `container` and a list of parsers, it also remember which parser should be applied next.

After that we have the "abstract class" (constructor function with method in the prototype which throws an exception) named `Parser` it defines a method `parse` which must be implemented by each parser.

After that we just define different concrete parsers and add them to the view. We can pass the states one by one (`View`'s `nextState`) or pass all states in a single method call (`View`'s `parse`). We can dynamically add new parsers.

A thing which can be approved is including flyweight factory for managing the parsers.

Approach with the "abstract" constructor function is also very useful when implementing different patterns like Template method for example.

- Edit may be there's a bit overhead because of the definition of all these constructor functions and objects. Everything can be done with callbacks i.e. each state to be a different function. I used this approach because I was looking for the easiest for understanding, clear from language specific features answer. I hope that I achieved it.

Comment: It looks very neat, but in which way is this 85 lines parser more efficient, maintainable and easy to understand than a simple 7 lines function gathering all the regex operations in one place. At the end of the day, the job is really done by the same regex replace operations, except that it takes more time to understand how it works and each time you have to add a "state", instead of adding one line, you need to add 4. What are the advantages here?

Comment: It gives you the flexibility of the State pattern. It don't give you another way of parsing the text but states which are independent. It can became more maintainable when you extend your functionality and your state encapsulate some extra data. It also is more reusable. Of course at the end of the day the work can be done within a single file with 10000 lines of code or within 10 files, each with 100 lines of code and separated concerns.

Comment: Still strikes me as hugely overkill. You would have to extend your functionality all the way to a fully fledged mark-up language before a solution like yours becomes more maintainable and justify the initial overhead/complexity. In the present case, it would be absurd to extend that much since it would merely replicates the functionality of HTML and as soon as this little formatting scheme reaches some serious level of complexity, it becomes far more efficient and user friendly to allow HTML and disable specific tags.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what you do, to extend your tagging system, you will need to:
1. define the tag, and 
2. replace it with equivalent HTML.

Even if you write your own parser in js, at the end of the day, you will still have to do the 2 above steps, so it is no more extensible than what you have now.

Regex is the tool for the job unless you have other requirements (i.e. as replace only within such an such element, but do something else in another element, which requires parsing).

You can wrap your regex calls in a function and simply add regex replaces to that function when you need to extend the feature. If needed in several pages, add it in an external js file.

```
function formatUserContent(text)
{
  text = text.replace(/\*([^\*]+)\*/g, '<b>$1</b>');
  text = text.replace(/\_([^\_]+)\_/g, '<u>$1</u>');
  text = text.replace(/\-([^\-]+)\-/g, '<s>$1</s>');
  text = text.replace(/\[([^\|].+)\|(.+)\]/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
  return text;
}
```

Once that's done, extending the feature is as simple as adding

```
text = text.replace(/\+([^\-]+)\+/g, '<em>$1</em>');
```

in the body of the function. I doubt that rolling out your own finite state machine will be any easier to extend, quite the opposite.

Spending hours on a finite state machine in the hope that it might save a few minutes at some unknown time in the future is just not a good investment... unless of course you want an excuse to write a finite state machine, in which case, go ahead.

As a side note, I would recommend making your regex a little more fool proof.

```
text = text.replace(/\[([^\|].+)\|\s*(http://.+)\]/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
```

(Unless you have UI elements that will do the job for the user)

Comment: If the site is accessible via https, just use "https?:".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use an existing library, for instance the Markdown library at http://www.showdown.im/

If you prefer to write your own, then I'd recommend looking at the source code to see how it's parsed (and maybe the source code for Markdown processors in other languages). Some recommendations for you:

- Use jQuery for manipulating the markup
- Don't use regular expressions for parsing a language. You'll run into problems when markup elements
  are mixed together.

Comment: I was about to start ranting about using regexes for nested tags, but realized that with this kind of markup you wouldn't expect the same tag to be nested.  What kind of issue could you get with regexes for this?

Comment: You might not expect tags to be nested, but the users may still use nested tags. Also, using regexes, you have to be careful that "_foo_ _bar_" is not marked up as "<u>foo_ _bar</u>".

Comment: He does not need to parse the HTML markup or any other "language", he needs to replace his own custom mark-up (clearly defined) by specific tags. Regex is appropriate for this task.

Comment: @Sylverdrag No, regexes are still not up to the task. Markup is recursive by nature, and regexes do not handle recursive languages. Users may still use embedded markup, and a regex can capture adjacent markup and treat it as a single one.

Comment: @Rob This is NOT a mark-up language, just a bit of formatting and NO, it is NOT recursive. Instead of a knee-jerk reaction because you have read "mark-up" and "regex" in the same sentence, think about the task at hand. It's not a parsing operation, it's a text replace operation. Go ahead and find some examples where a regex would fail at replacing predefined characters like "*".

Comment: The "just a bit of formatting" is a markup language. It is not a knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: @rob Great, then you will have no problem to give me a few examples where regex will be inadequate.

Comment: @Rob Here: http://jsfiddle.net/NwRCm/5. Show me some realistic examples of "recursive formatting" and how regex fails.